# 'vite build' only last commit of branch?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

Is there a way I can make `vite build` in my Vue 3 project only build the latest commit on the current branch, as opposed to the exact current state of the branch?

Comment: Assuming you're talking about git commits. You can use `git stash` to stash your changes before you build. Or make a new branch, commit your work in progress there and then go back to the branch that's ready to be built.

Comment: build tools (vite) and versions control tool (git) have no relation at all and they should not relate to each other. So using `git stash` as the comment above is a good solution. Additionally, you can config `prebuild` and `postbuild` scripts to auto `stash` and `pop stash` every build. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts

Comment: @Duannx awesome, prebuild/postbuild is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Off the top of your head... any idea why adding prebuild now causes the build script to display "command not found"?     "prebuild": "git stash --all",
    "build": "vite build",
    "postbuild": "git stash pop stash@{0}",

Comment: which command was not found?